# How to use ng-min or ng-pattern together with ng-required?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have some form fields that shouldn't be required sometimes. I want to use `ng-min` or `ng-pattern` together with `ng-required`.

But if I delete field value itself (or make them invalid somehow) when field is not required (`ng-required` is falsy) the form still is invalid state because of wrong value that doesn't satisfy either `ng-min` or `ng-pattern`.

I assume that `ng-pattern` and `ng-min` won't mark field as invalid when it's not required (`ng-required` is falsy)

Answer (score 1):

This sounds like a perfect use of a custom validator. More information from the angular team on custom validators can be found [here](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/cookbook/form-validation.html#!#custom-validation). I would simply create maybe a couple different custom validators that check if the value is null and or meets some additional pattern or numerical requirement.

There may also be a validtor library on npm that has this ready to go for you.

Simple Example (Not Tested)

```
export const customMin(minimum: number): ValidatorFn {
  return (control: AbstractControl): {[key: string]: any} => {
    const val = control.value;
    const valid = val && val >= minimum ? true
    if (!val) {
      return {"minValue": true};
    } else {
      return val >= minimum ? return {"minValue": true} : null
    }
  };
}
```

Comment: Yep, i was going to use this solution, already use this for 1 field. Was trying to find proper way. I thought there should be ng-min & ng-required solution and i just didn't see something obvious. Thanks for the feedback.